# Java JDBC Log in Form

Tags: java, database, swing, jdbc, authentication

I can't seem to get the password and user name on my Java JTextfield and Passwordfield, what I was trying to do is compare user input and check them if the username and password is stored in the database, if so they will be logged in, but the problem is my getText() on my password field is deprecated how would I fix this??

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Login extends JFrame {

private JLabel nameLabel;
private JLabel passwordLabel;
private JTextField nameText;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
private JButton submitButton;
Connection conn = null;

public Login(){

super("Log in!");
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
setVisible(true);
setSize(178,190);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

nameLabel = new JLabel("User ID: ");
add(nameLabel);

nameText = new JTextField(10);
add(nameText);

passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
add(passwordLabel);

passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
add(passwordField);

submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
add(submitButton);

ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
submitButton.addActionListener(handler);
}

private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

String user = nameText.getText();
String pass = passwordField.getText();
try{
Jdbc test = new Jdbc();
conn = test.dbConn();
String query = "SELECT employee_ID,employee_password FROM user where ='"+user+"'";

}catch(Exception eee){
eee.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: This might help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [getPassword()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) instead of `getText()` method.

```
  char []passChars=passwordField.getPassword();
   if(passChars!=null) { 
       String pass=new String(passChars);
       String sql="SELECT employee_ID,employee_password FROM user 
                             where user=? and employee_password=?";
       PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       ps.setString(1,user);
       ps.setString(2,pass);
       ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next()) {
          //found
       }
       else{
          //not found
       }
       rs.close();
       ps.close();
       conn.close();
   }
```

One thing worth noting is that don't use hard-coded sql statement. Use `PreparedStatement` to escape string to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: can you please explain why the `gettext()` wont work?? (while passwordfield is also a textcomponent)

Comment: @Sanjay - Of course getText() will work with JPasswordField but take a look at API : For security reasons, this method is deprecated. Use the * getPassword method instead. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText() )

Comment: what's the use of the questions marks? I don't seem to get it.how would  I compare it to my user input? then put it in the query?

Comment: lastly what's the use of  ps.setString(1,user);
       ps.setString(2,pass); ??

Answer (score 2):

```
char[] p = passField.getPassword();
String password = new String(p);
```

I think you should use PreparedStatement

```
PreparedStatement prepstmt = con
        .prepareStatement("SELECT employee_ID,employee_password FROM user where username = ? AND Password = ? ");
    prepstmt.setString(1, user);
    prepstmt.setString(2, password);


    ResultSet rs;
    rs = prepstmt.executeQuery();

    boolean found = rs.next();
    if (found)
      System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    prepstmt.close();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Swing's JPasswordField has the getPassword() method that returns a char array*.

```
String passText = new String(passField.getPassword());
```